# Using AND function in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, column-formatting, formula

I am trying to create relatively simple conditional column formatting in a SharePoint Online list.

This works (the conditions 1==1 and 2==2 are placeholders to simplify the example here):

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "style": {
      "color": "=if(1==1, '#ff0000', '#ff00ff')"
   }
}
```

But when I introduce an AND function, it doesn't work (no formatting occurs):

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "style": {
      "color": "=if(AND(1==1, 2==2), '#ff0000', '#ff00ff')"
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `&&` for Anding conditions and `||` for Oring

This should work for you:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "style": {
      "color": "=if(1==1 && 2==2, '#ff0000', '#ff00ff')"
   }
}
```

Comment: That works.  Thanks!!